# How can I fit and automatically move and scale an image in between two headers?

Tags: html, css

I want to place a logo image between two headers and have it resize and move so that it stays relative to the text.

```css
body{
            background-color: black;
        }
        .logotext{
            padding: 25px;;
            font-family: abnes;
            color:white;
        }
        #h1{
            float: left;
        }
        #h2{
            float: right;
        }
        #logo{
            float:inherit;
         }
```

```html
<head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
            <body>
                <div class=logotext>
                    <h1 id="h1">Huron</h1>
                    <h1 id="h2">Interplanetary</h1>
                    <img id=logo src="https://dummyimage.com/600x600/000/fff">
                </div>
            </body>
        </head>
```

I want it to look like this: Huron 0 Interplanetary
(where 0 is the logo image).

Simple question, but I'm learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `justify-content: space-between` to your `.logotext` so it stays centered when ever you zoom in or out. make sure to also add `display: flex` otherwise `justify-content` won´t work.

```
.logotext{
    padding: 25px;
    font-family: abnes;
    color:white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for. You can look on [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for a full explanation on flexbox

Comment: Sadly that dont work

Comment: Make sure your logo isn´t too large either. set a proper `width` and `height` to `#logo` so it doesn´t break.

Comment: I believe you are correct. Thank you!

Comment: I had to change html so that img came before #h2